# ARKit ARSCNView: use of ultra-wide camera or zoom?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, arscnview

I have an ARKit `ARSCNView` providing an AR experience with the default rear-facing camera. I would like to use other cameras like the ultra-wide camera for that. If possible, it would be great to provide fluent zoom. Is it possible?

I did some research and found out one needs to loop over supported video formats of the AR configuration (e.g. `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.supportedVideoFormats`). This gives an array of a few video formats with different fps values, ratios, ... But, there is always the `AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInWideAngleCamera`. Ultra-wide or Tele does not seem to be included. How do we get the AR experience with an other camera than the default (wide) one?

Thanks in advance.